# efficient way to debug controller post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a controller that serves as webservice.
I want to debug the following method:

```
public ActionResult CreateVar(string clientId, string signature, string timestamp)
```

Because it's a controller and not WCF, and also it's a POST and not GET - I cannot invoke it simply.

How can I invoke it for debugging, perhaps through fiddler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MVC.ApiExplorer](http://millionbonus.bitbucket.org/mvc.apiexplorer/). The tool automatically generates test page which lists all your actions of controller. I've used it while I was working with others on an asp.net MVC project.

Answer (score 2):

You can write unit tests for controller methods. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to invoke it to test (i.e. you haven't written unit tests to call the method), I would recommend using Fiddler, capturing the POST request, and then replaying the post request whenever needed.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Note: I would also recommend that testing your method with unit tests would be the best. If you need HttpContext, there are several good articles on mocking it.

Thanks,

Hal

Answer (score 0):

First right click on web service project and **Debug** -> **Start new instance**
and than same thing on your main project

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple html three text-boxes for three parameters of the post action. Wrap this in a form tag pointing to your action. Add a button in this form.

Answer (score 0):

cURL is your friend. This is a little command line tool to GET/POST urls. You can download a win32 version from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

To debug your application do the following from your command line:

```
curl -d "clientId=1&signature=s&timestamp=20111103" http://localhost:1479/servicePath
```

You should have visual studio debugger attached to the web dev server.